# Programmable, mobile device

Tags: mobile, mobile-devices

I have been searching for this since about a month now, and it is beginning to drive me crazy!

What I want is:

- A mobile device
- At least 2 buttons as an input
- An LCD or any other display of any size as an output
- It should be **programmable**, in any way, may it be assembler, C or BASIC.

(I would be already happy if you could display *Hello World* with the device on a button press, or draw a line, or even play a homebrew tetris)

As you can see from the list, my requirements from the device are quite low. I'd be happy with something like a pocket computer from the 80's.

I have looked into programmable (graphing) calculators, but the problem is that they're just so **expensive** for what I'm trying to do. I really can't afford something like them.

- Do you have any idea if there is a device like this for sale somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow. Welcome to the site. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

What you might require is PIC-GSM DEVELOPMENT BOARD some thing like

this [link text](http://www.olimex.com/dev/pic-gsm.html)

Or something more straight forward but could possible be use in a mobile form

a picaxe see @ www.rev-ed.co.uk picaxe/